# What is the proper way to provide an object to a static class's static method?

Tags: c#

E.g. If I have a static class:

```
static class A
{

static int Method_1(){ Method_2(); }
static int Method_2(){ Method_3(); }
static int Method_3(){ Method_4(); }
static int Method_4() {  // Need to use the object here only  }

}
```

Here, `Method_4` needs an object, but the problem is I don't call `Method_4` directly from my instance class. The instance class calls only `Method_1` and if I pass the object to `Method_1`, I have to unnecessarily provide that object's type as parameter in each of the methods in the call chain - Method_1 -> Method_2 -> Method_3 -> Method_4

None of the in between methods require to use the object.

What is the proper way to give the object to the `Method_4`. Should I include its parameter in all of the methods?

Comment: can you make this object a static member variable of the class so that Method_4 can access it ?

Comment: @auburg I don't recommend it, see my answer.

Comment: I don't think you could avoid passing the object down to the call chain. The only thing that could alleviate the situation happens only if Method4() could handle the situation in which the object is null or has a default value. In that case you can make the parameter optional and pass along a null/default value for your object. In this scenario you could call Method1 without passing a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the object is needed, then it isn't "unnecessarily" passing it around - it is *necessarily* passing it around. So: you're going to need to add a parameter to all of them and pass it along (or alternatively: consider making these be *instance* method on the type that is needed).

So

```cs
static int Method_1(Whatever thing){ Method_2(thing); }
static int Method_2(Whatever thing){ Method_3(thing); }
static int Method_3(Whatever thing){ Method_4(thing); }
static int Method_4(Whatever thing) {  // Need to use the object here only  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend indeed to add it as a parameter to all your methods:

```
static class A
{
static int Method_1(object x){ Method_2(x); }
static int Method_2(object x){ Method_3(x); }
static int Method_3(object x){ Method_4(x); }
static int Method_4(object x) {  Console.WriteLine(x);  }
}
```

As an alternative, you could also store it in a private field:

```
static class A
{
private static object field;
static int Method_1(object x){ field = x; Method_2(); }
static int Method_2(){ Method_3(); }
static int Method_3(){ Method_4(); }
static int Method_4() {  Console.WriteLine(field );  }

}
```

But this has two severe disadvantages: First, your code is not thread-safe anymore. Also, you will get problems if you want to call `Method_4` directly at some point (because there is still the value stored from your last call of `Method_1`, which could lead to unpredictable side-effects).